# cabal: ghc build with -dynamic and shared library

Tags: haskell, cabal, ffi

I'm trying to build a dynamic application with GHC, this is my cabal file:

```
executable app
  main-is: Main.hs
  c-sources: cbits/foo.cpp
  cc-options: -shared -fPIC
  include-dirs: /usr/local/lib/llvm-6.0/include
  extra-libraries: stdc++ clang
  extra-lib-dirs: /usr/local/lib/llvm-6.0/lib
  other-modules:
    ...
```

I need to use the FFI and I'm working on MacOS. I'm getting a linker error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_clangToJSON",
>   referenced from:
>         _ClangziCParser_hppTree_info in CParser.o

This is indeed a foreign function that I'm trying to access, I've had success with the following arguments to ghc in a Makefile:

Building FFI impl, shared library:

```
 clang -fPIC -shared foo.cpp -o foo.so
```

Building Main.hs with the shared library foo.so:

```
ghc -dynamic Main.hs -o  -lfoo -L. -optl-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN'
```

I've managed to make cabal running in `dynamic` mode with `--enable-shared` but I need to make the clang inside cabal generate a .so. I'm searching in
`dist/build/app` and I can't find a .so, even with the `-shared` option added to my `cc-options`. How can I generate a .so and then get cabal to link with it dynamically?

Comment: I didn't get what are you asking. What's `foo.so`? Anyways, take a look at Cabal's `foreign-library` stanza, it might be relevant.

Comment: you can see in my last clang step, foo.so is a shared library generated from clang and my foreign code.

Comment: If you want to link to it, add it to extra-libraries: `extra-libraries: stdc++ clang foo`.

Comment: Yeah for some reason it doesn’t see the library even when the .so is in the path, any success getting static linking with ffi on Mac? Static linking doesn’t work on Mac the same way it does for Linux.